# Mongodb duplicate key with empty database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am running mongod, and trying to save data inside a collection. I defined

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Person = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    name:String

},{ collection: 'customers' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', Person);
```

But later on, when I want to save a data e.g

```
var p = new Person({
  id:1,
  name:"John"
});

p.save(function(err,doc){
   if(err){
    console.log(err)
 }
}
```

it throws an error

> message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: Person index: id_-1
>   dup key: { : 1 }',

But in mongo, when I do

```
db.Person.count() // returns 0
show collections // nothing
```

indicating that the data has not beet saved insid db. Why does it keep throwing error about duplicating key?

Comment: Try running `db.Person.getIndexes()`?

Comment: returns empty array

Comment: Try `db.customers.count()`

Comment: You are checking collection count within appropriate db right?

Comment: yes , i restarded db and it started to work... i have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose schemas, the `id` field is special (it is string representation of `_id` field).

You should name it `_id` or you can remove it, the `_id` is implicitly there. And then use `_id` when creating new object.

Example :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Person = new Schema({
    name:String

},{ collection: 'customers' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', Person);
```

---

```
var p = new Person({
  _id:1,
  name:"John"
});

p.save(function(err,doc){
   if(err){
    console.log(err)
 }
}
```

or you dont have to write id, it is implicitly autogenerated

```
var p = new Person({
  name:"John"
});

p.save(function(err,doc){
   if(err){
    console.log(err)
 }
}
```